# QT QGraphicsView rotation

Tags: c++, qt

Disclaimer: I am pretty much a beginner with QT.
I've been struggling for some time to rotate a QGraphicsView (no 3D rotation) but, despite what i do, it doesn't work. I have tried:

```
QTransform transform;
transform.rotate(45);
ui->graphicsView->setTransform(transform);
```

or more simply:

```
ui->graphicsView->rotate(45);
```

These seem like very straightforward ways to do it that should work, but for some reason, whenever i run it, the QGraphicsView doesn't rotate at all. If possible, i'd like some direct and easy to understand code snippets, and/or what i'm doing wrong.
EDIT: This is the code in the widget cpp file i have problems with. It should be a simple timer with an animated hourglass icon. It gets repeated every .5 seconds.

```
void Widget::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event)
{
  ++timeFlag;
  ++timerFlag;
  if (timerFlag < 115){
      animateTimer = QString("\":/new/100/timerFrames/timerIconFrame%1.png\"").arg(timerFlag);
              QPixmap pix(animateTimer);
              pixmapitem.setPixmap(pix);
              scene.addItem(&pixmapitem);
              ui->graphicsView_2->setScene(&scene);
  }    
  if (timerFlag >= 115 && timerFlag < 119){
  //
  }
  if(timerFlag == 119){
     ui->graphicsView_2->setStyleSheet("border-image:url(:/new/100/timerIconPix.PNG);border:0px;}");
  }
  if(timerFlag == 120){
    timerFlag = 0;
  }
  if (timeFlag==2){
    timeFlag = 0;
    if(sec>=10){
      ui->label_2->setText(QString("%1:%2").arg(min).arg(sec));
    } else {
      ui->label_2->setText(QString("%1:0%2").arg(min).arg(sec));
    }
    ++sec;
    if (sec == 60) {
      sec = 0;
      ++min;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Kuba All of my code is in a widget cpp file, however as you asked i edited in my code. Hopefully you can help me anyways.

Comment: "All of my code is in a widget cpp" It's your job to move it all to a single   file (any name but usually `main.cpp`) and minimize out everything that's unnecessary. That's what it means to ask a good question. In most cases, you should do much more work than whoever answers it. While you do that work, you can often find the answer yourself. That's the whole point: only if you've done the work of code minimization and no solution is apparent you should ask a question. It will be very likely by then that the question will be decent at that point.

Comment: @Kuba I'm trying to do this: animateTimer = QString("\":/new/100/timerFrames/timerIconFrame%1.png\"").arg(timerFlag);
    ui->label->setText(animateTimer);
    QImage image(animateTimer);
    QGraphicsPixmapItem item( QPixmap::fromImage(image));
    QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene;
    scene->addItem(&item);
    ui->graphicsView_2->setScene(scene); However, it doesn't change what the graphicsView displays.

Comment: Add the code to the question, not as a comment. The item will be destructed as soon as the function is returned from - that's your problem. Make the scene and the item, both, simple (non-pointer) members of your widget class.

Comment: @Kuba I've added QGraphicsScene*scene;
    QGraphicsPixmapItem item; in the header and changed the code i posted earlier accordingly; however, the program now crashes as soon as i start the timer.

Comment: Why is `scene` a pointer? It shouldn't be. Alas, you really need to post the entire code. Just edit your question!

Comment: @Kuba Scene is not a pointer anymore. Now whenever the timer starts running i get an error saying "ASSERT: "ret.at(0).isLetter()" in file io\qfilesystemengine_win.cpp, line 586" which crashes the program. I've updated the code in the question to reflect the new changes.

Comment: Please post *all of your code* that is on the call stack when the crash happens. In the debugger, when it crashes, you'll see a list of methods. Some of them are inside of Qt, some are in the standard library, but many of them will be your code. Please post the source to all of such methods that are yours, and are on the call stack while you crash. That's at the very minimum.

Comment: @Kuba The only thing that is on the call stack when the crash happens which is mine is Widget::timerEvent. When i click on it in the debugger, i get an arrow pointing to QPixmap pix(animateTimer);, which seems for some reason to be the cause of the crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're merely decorating the `QGraphicsView` using the style mechanism. You could have used a plain `QWidget` instead, since you don't use *any* graphics view functionality. None of the images in the stylesheet are what the view actually displays. The image must be on the scene displayed by the view.

Set the image on a `QGraphicsPixmapItem`, add that item to a scene, set the scene on the view, and *then* the transformations will work. You can then keep replacing the pixmap in the timer handler.

Finally, you must also check the timer id in the `timerEvent`. I assume that you're using a `QBasicTimer`, say called `m_timer`, you'd then check as follows:

```
void Widget::timerEvent(QTimerEvent * ev) {
  if (ev->timerId() != m_timer.timerId()) return;
  ... // rest of the code
}
```

As you can see, the code that you've not included in the original question was absolutely essential! Without it, the question was wholly off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement a QGraphicsView, a QGraphicsScene and then add something that inherits from QGraphicsItem to that scene to rotate.

Here is an example that rotates a QWidget in a QGraphicsView:

```
QGraphicsView* view = new QGraphicsView(parent);
QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene(view);
view->setScene(scene);

// Widget to rotate - important to not parent it
QWidget* widget = new QWidget();
QProxyWidget proxy_widget = scene_->addWidget(widget);

QPropertyAnimation* animation = new QPropertyAnimation(proxy_widget, "rotation");
animation->setDuration(5000);
animation->setStartValue(0);
animation->setEndValue(360); 
animation->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::Linear);
animation->start(QAbstractAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
```